# How to give url properly to anchor tag in asp.net using jquery?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

I have written jquery in .net application as

```
Function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
        var filename = args.get_fileName();
        var contentType = args.get_contentType();
        var folder = "~/Uploads/";
        var text = "Size of " + filename + " is " + args.get_length() + " bytes";
        if (contentType.length > 0) {
            text += "and content type is '" + contentType + "'.";
            text += "<a href='" + folder + filename + "'" + filename + "</a>";
        }
        document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerText = text;
    }
```

Now my issue is I am not able to give path accurately in the line

```
 text += "<a href='" + folder + filename + "'" + filename + "</a>";
```

Please help me!!!

Comment: `<a>` tag is not in correct format. Should be `"<a href='" + folder + filename + "'" + filename + "></a>";`. You forgot to add `>`.

Comment: missing end  > on creating anchor

Comment: Do you need to include a `/` between folder and filename?

Comment: @ppittle: No, `folder = "~/Uploads/"` (already has trailing `/`)

Comment: how about using `document.createElement("A")` and `document.createTextNode` to generate the desired markup?

Comment: As a general guideline, delimit JavaScript *html strings* with `single quotes`, so that you can have the correct `double-quotes` on the attributes inside elements. I now tend to always use single-quotes for strings in jQuery/JavaScript because of this :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues to sort out:

### 1) "~/"

"~/" as a relative path is for use *server-side in .Net*. Javascript (really your browser) does not know what to do with that URL.

As a little trick, you can inject an *application root URL* using this Razor code `@(Url.Content("~/"))` but that means your function needs to be in a razor page and not a separate JS file.

If your JS is "elsewhere", inject the path as a Javascript variable (e.g. `window.rootUrl = "@(Url.Content("~/"))"`) using a small script section on the page.

### 2) Missing '>'

You are missing a closing `>` in your generated anchor.

### 3) innerHTML, not innerText

You need to set the innerHTML property, or you will get raw text. You will probably need to tweak the formatting of the output (line breaks or spans/paragraphs) to make it look pretty (e.g. you have no space before the anchor at the moment).

### Put it all together and you get something like:

```
function UploadComplete(sender, args) {
    var filename = args.get_fileName();
    var contentType = args.get_contentType();
    var folder = '@(Url.Content("~/"))Uploads/';
    var text = 'Size of ' + filename + ' is ' + args.get_length() + ' bytes';
    if (contentType.length > 0) {
        text += 'and content type is "' + contentType + '". ';
        text += '<a href="' + folder + filename + '">' + filename + '</a>';
    }
    document.getElementById('lblStatus').innerHTML = text;
}
```

*As I said in comment, I strongly recommend using the single quote as a string delimiter in jQuery/JavaScript so that any HTML strings have double-quotes on attributes.*

### 4) jQuery?

You tagged the question with jQuery too, which would shorten the last line to:

```
    $('#lblStatus').html(text);
```

*Apologies for any typos, I typed all this off the top of my head and did not verify it.*